# Coalesce / defer multiple child scope $apply calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my app I am receiving data via an HTTP channel that's handled in a custom way. I'm building some [data] objects from the pipe, wrap them in a scope.$new(true) and when I receive an update call childScope.$apply() to set the new properties.

This works fine for light loads, all the watchers get notified and has really been running without any issues or missed updates.

Now I'm trying to push a lot more updates and don't know if the pattern used above is the way to go. I think (though have not checked) that each call to $apply calls the digest on the root scope and I want to coalesce these on browser cycles or ~50ms intervals. Currently, whenever I receive ~100 updates on 5000 objects/scopes it kills the browser.

I saw that angular docs say each scope has an $applyAsync method but I cannot find it anywhere, this would be essentially what I am after.

Is this a bad idea and the performance is already good enough? Should I implement my own applyAsync method by using $browser.defer() or some other method?

Edit: just tested the code and indeed the $rootScope.$digest is called for each child scope $apply(). Perhaps moving this part away from Angular JS and using a listener-based approach is better, so this is also a valid answer.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$applyAsync

Comment: I was thinking of https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$applyAsync otherwise I need to implement a custom $apply using the $evalAsync, which can be done as well. I am asking what would be the recommended way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used evalAsync and this seems to work as intended.

I probably need to call $digest (or $apply) every so often to make sure there are no pending scope changes but I have not seen the need to do this yet.

So my idea would be to:

- call evalAsync for all the scope changes that need to happen very fast
- increment a counter before the evalAsync call
- set a variable with the current time inside the evalAsync function parameter and decrement the counter
- on a timer (50-100ms) see if the counter is >0 and if the last evaluation time was some time ago (>50-100ms) and if yes force a digest loop.

I will not mark this as a correct answer since it does not seem like the best idea but it was the best I could come up with and it does the job as intended.

Comment: For future reference, a similar feature seems to have been implemented in angular: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/ea6fc6e69c2a2aa213c71ed4e917a0d54d064e4c